# Fiber equal in nbhd and flat gives open immersion.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

See : [Fibers equal implies schemes equal in a neighborhood](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330308/fibers-equal-implies-schemes-equal-in-a-nbhd) for background to this question.
Let us keep the same assumptions as we do in the above. Let us assume further that Z is flat over T and f is of finite type. How could I show that thete exists an open nbhd $y \in V$ such that
$Z \cap f^{-1}(V) \rightarrow f^{-1}(V)$ is an open immersion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is false without stronger hypothesis (as properness or connectedness for example).

Let $Y$ be integral of positive dimension. Let $y\in Y$ be a closed point, $W=Y\setminus \{ 0\}$. Consider $X$ the disjoint union $\mathbb A^1_W\coprod Y$ with the natural structure of $Y$-scheme, let $Z=\{ 0_W\} \coprod Y$ where $0_W\simeq W$ is the zero section of $\mathbb A^1_W$. Then $Z$ is flat over $Y$, it contains the fiber $X_y=\{ y\}$. But for any $y'\in W$, $Z_{y'}=\{ y'\} \coprod \{ y'\}$  is not open in $X_{y'}=\mathbb A^1_{y'} \coprod \{ y'\}$.

You should write to the author of the book to point out this mistake.

Comment: +1 Dear answerer, don't you think that writing to the author to tell him he made **a mistake !** would be  extremely rude ? What I  say is: let's  not tell him. Let's leave him happy.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Dear Georges, this would not be the first time he get noticed a mistake...